# Cancel a Runtime Permission request?

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

In the android documentation for Runtime permissions for Marshmallow the following code comment refers to cancellation of a permission request:

```
case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

I have not been able to determine how to actually cancel a request for a permission such that the grantResults array returns with a length == 0.  The dialog asking for the permission only lets the user allow or deny the request, so cancelling the request by user action isn't obvious.

However, I ran monkey and it managed to accomplish this at least once.

The documentation for onRequestPermissionResult indicates that cancellation is possible.

How can I reproduce the case where grantResults will have a length of 0, which indicates it is a cancelled request?  (The String[] grantResults is not null, but has length 0)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Are you running into a specific problem?

Comment: I've tried using back button and pushing the app to the background when the request permission dialog box is open.  I'm at a loss as to how to replicate a request cancellation and therefore can't verify the bug is fixed. Also, monkey has caused the app to crash if the above check is not added.

Comment: OK, so I see what you mean.  That dialog appears to be impossible to dismiss without killing the app or choosing an option.  I'll think about it some more.

Comment: Note that `permissions` array will be empty too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was testing runtime permissions on another application and managed to create a cancel permissions request rather simply.

In the instance of a screen rotation, Android will cancel a permissions request dialog that is currently being displayed and then recreate it.